# Upgrade PHP, now Phalcon / Nginx no longer works

Tags: php, nginx, phalcon

Upgraded from PHP 5.3 to PHP 5.4 and now, all Phalcon sites on the server give a 502 error.

Box info:
Centos 6.5
PHP 5.4
nginx 1.6
Phalcon 2.0

The error messages:
Browser shows:

```
502 Bad Gateway
```

Nginx Log:

```
[error] 27662#0: *6 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream
```

PHP-FPM log:

```
WARNING: [pool www] child 27667 exited on signal 4 (SIGILL) after 272.690790 seconds from start
```

nginx and php-fpm have been restarted numerous times.
Phalcon has be reinstalled numerous times.

PHP-FPM Conf:

```
include=/etc/php-fpm.d/*.conf
pid = /var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.pid
```

PHP-FPM www.conf

```
listen = /var/run/php5-fpm.sock
listen.owner = nginx
listen.group = nginx
user = nginx;
group = nginx;
pm = dynamic
pm.max_children = 5
pm.start_servers = 2
pm.min_spare_servers = 1
pm.max_spare_servers = 3
pm.max_requests = 500
security.limit_extensions = false
php_value[session.save_handler] = files
php_value[session.save_path] = /var/lib/php/session
```

the session path has already been checked for permissions and ownership, so that is fine.

Nginx Conf:

```
server {
listen      IPADDR:80;
server_name sub.domain.com;

index index.php index.html index.htm;
set $root_path '/var/www/projectname/public';
root $root_path;

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @php_mvc;
}

location @php_mvc {
    rewrite ^(.+)$ /index.php$1 last;
}

location ~ ^(.+\.php)(/.*)?$ {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)?$;

    set $script_filename $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;

    if (!-e $script_filename) {
        return 404;
    }

    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;

    fastcgi_param   APPLICATION_ENV development;
    fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME $script_filename;
    fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_NAME $fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param   PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
}

location ~* ^/(css|img|js|flv|swf|download|images)/(.+)$ {
    root $root_path;
}
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I've received this error before and after a ridiculous amount Nginx specific research ended up discovering a rogue PHP `exit;` that was left hanging around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I finally found answer in Phalcon's github issue list.

This post:
[Phalcon Github issue 2593](https://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon/issues/2593)

The solution was to remove all my phalcon code, and then recompile it by hand via:

```
cd build/64bits
phpize
export CFLAGS="-O2 -g"
./configure 
make
sudo make install
```

I also git cloned a fresh version of that source to make sure. The removing of the previous code was more for me to make sure it didn't grab any cached configuration. Hopefully this helps someone else save several hours!

Comment: Was about to write that you should recompile phalcon for new configuration.